# How does one extract the name of a variable in a function that is called from another function in R?

Tags: r, variables, extract

My question is how to extract the name of a variable from a function that is called in another function in R?

To illustrate, here is an example:

```
a <- function(variable) {

    print(deparse(substitute(variable)))

    internala(substitute(variable))

}

internala <- function(variableXX) {

    namex=deparse(substitute(variableXX))

    print(namex)
}
```

Calling the function  `a`  gives the following result:

```
>a(whatever)

[1] "whatever"

[1] "substitute(variable)"
```

which means that i can extract the name of the variable `whatever` from `a`, but not from `internala`.

Any thoughts on this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Maria

Comment: Just to be clear, what is the behavior that you want?  I'm guessing that you want `a(whatever)` to print `whatever` twice?  If you also execute `internala(whatever)` do you also want the output to be `whatever`?  What if you call foo <- function(b) { a(b) } ; foo(bar)?

Comment: yes, u guessed correctly, i want a(whatever) to print whatever twice, internala(whatever) to print whatever and, where i actually got stuck is exactly what you pointed out, that is if i have another function foo <- function(b) { a(b) }, i would like foo(bar) to print bar twice.
Is that clear? Do you have any idea of how to do this? 
tnx a lot!
maria

Comment: Based on the last case, it seems like you want to expand the expression all the way to the top level call, but no further?  So that if there were also foo2 <- function(b) { foo(b + 1) } you would want foo2(bar) to print bar + 1 twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change `a` function to substitute argument of an `internala` function and `eval` it:

```
a <- function(variable) {
    print(deparse(substitute(variable)))
    eval(substitute(internala(variable))) # this is only change
}

internala <- function(variableXX) {
    namex=deparse(substitute(variableXX))
    print(namex)
}

a(whatever)
```

As hadley suggest its better to directly pass names. I usually do something like that:

```
a <- function(variable, vname=deparse(substitute(variable))) {
    print(vname)
    internala(variable, vname)
}

internala <- function(variableXX, namex=deparse(substitute(variableXX))) {
    print(namex)
}

a(whatever)
```

Each function could be call without passing name, but you can override it. For example:

```
a(whatever, "othername")
```

Answer (score 6):

You're better off not messing around with substitute and friends - you are likely to create a function that will be very hard to program against.  Why not just pass in the name of the variable explicitly as a string?

Comment: Definitely; working with string names is much more straight forward.

Comment: This was helpful (thanks), but inside the function I then had to do `var <- get(var_as_string)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that works for me. However I' m not sure if this is the optimum solution

```
a <- function(variable) {
print(deparse(substitute(variable)))
my_command <- paste('internala(',substitute(variable),')',sep = '')
eval(parse(text = my_command))
}

internala <- function(variableXX) {
namex=deparse(substitute(variableXX))
print(namex)
}
```

Comment: Upvote because it seems to does the trick except for two minor quibbles:  1.) you should deparse the substitute, otherwise you'll get an error if you call a(b + 1).  2.) based on maria's comments you'll have to go up parent frames too.